# Sorting divs based on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I asked this question a few days ago about sorting div based on there class names. I was thinking, is it possible to sort the divs when the screen width is lower than 1200? Above the 1200 he sort the div-elements back on the old position? (It should even work when the screen resizes on the desktop)

I tried to save the old order in an array before this function runs. I add a data-attribute to every single row with a number 1 - x. But it is a little overkill I think..

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

order = function(){
    var elem = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

    function sortMe(a, b) {
        return a.className.split(' ').pop() < b.className.split(' ').pop();
    }

    $('.container').append(elem);
};

// now the rows are sorted when the screen is smaller then 975 or 1185 but it possible to get the old order back when the screen is bigger then 975 or 1185 (when the screen resizes)
if($('body').hasClass('front')){
    if(windowWidth < 975){
        order();
    }
}else{
    if(windowWidth < 1185){
        order();
    }
}
```

Because on a desktop (> 1185) the admin decides the sorting in the CMS but if the screen is smaller than (< 1185) I decide the sorting and that is based on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a `data-attr` before the order functions runs. When the screensize is bigger than x I sorting the element back based on the value of the `data-attr` without using an array. If it is smaller I sorting them based on my class.

You have two sorting functions, one for the desktop and one for the mobile. Works well for me.